# Some markdown syntax is not showing in IntelliJ preview

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax, markdown

I have a URL that's not showing up in preview within IntelliJ;
**<mbojorq3@sample_email>** and the preview is not showing any changes.

I am also trying to make a sentence either **bold** or *italic* by using * *

Would I need to make any changes in order to see them within the preview?

Comment: Does https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-225266 look like your case? If not, [submit a new bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) and attach [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes exactly my case

Comment: I added the CSS Rule and that seemed to solve the Italic issue, but still having issues with the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-225266). You can try the workaround with overriding the font used for Markdown preview:

[image: CSS]

I've submitted [a new bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246427) for the email autolink problem.

Comment: Thats the same problem I am running into. I am following the [markdown guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#urls-and-email-addresses)

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246427 for updates.